# In need of very small open-source kernels

Tags: c++, operating-system, linux-kernel, kernel

I need a very tiny open-source kernel(the tiniest you know) with at least a console i/o with/without GUI that I could compile into object code and load it into RAM using a simple bootloader(that I already have).  the goal is to be able to do read/write to the disk from within the kernel. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please define "tiny". I see in a comment below you're also asking about commercial use; do you have licensing restrictions too? eg. No GPL? Also, what is your target architecture and use-case? Will a single-process RTOS solve your problem, for example?

Comment: something like I'd like to base my project on a free kernel but the project won't be free. and yes, a single process RTOS would solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[FreeRTOS](http://www.freertos.org/) might be worth a look. Plenty of supported platforms, small footprint. The free version is GPL which will probably hinder any closed source development you might want to do, but there are commercial releases with much more liberal licenses you could use if you were willing to pay up.

[ucLinux](http://www.uclinux.org/) is slightly more heaviweight, but can still work on systems without MMUs. I've never actually tried to deploy this one myself, I've only used systems that already had a suitable image available for them (old Gumstix board).

If you're going to target x86 you can go for something a bit more substantial. The MicroCore variant of [Tiny Core Linux](http://distro.ibiblio.org/tinycorelinux/) will demand a few megabytes of RAM.

Answer (score 1):

Tanenbaum's work and a subject of a very famous CS debate:

[MINIX homepage](http://www.minix3.org/)

[MINIX in wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MINIX)

Comment: can I use it in a commercial app?

Comment: I mean.. I want to create a bootable media from which I would load the kernel into memory and offer some further functionalities.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_license